# Can Quartz Scheduler Run jobs serially?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I'm looking into using Quartz Scheduler, and I was wondering if it was possible to schedule jobs not by time, but when another job finishes.  So, when Job A is done, it starts Job B.  When that's done, it starts Job C, etc.

```
Job A -> Job B -> Job C -> Job A... continuously.
```

Is this the right tool for the job?  Or should I be looking into something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [`JobChainingJobListener`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html), built-in to Quartz (bold mine):

> Keeps a collection of mappings of which Job to trigger after the completion of a given job. If this listener is notified of a job completing that has a mapping, then it will then attempt to trigger the follow-up job. This achieves **"job chaining"**, or a **"poor man's workflow"**.

That's right, you are looking for a process or workflow engine. Have a look at [activiti](/questions/tagged/activiti) or [jbpm](/questions/tagged/jbpm).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) project I have been involved in. QuartzDesk is a management and monitoring platform for Quartz-based apps and in version 2.0 we have added a new [job chaining engine](https://www.quartzdesk.com/documentation/features#job-chaining) to the platform.

The engine allows you to orchestrate the execution of your jobs and there is no need to modify your application code in any way. Job chains can be dynamically updated through the QuartzDesk GUI without any disruption to your application.

[image: QuartzDesk Job chain Target Editor]