# Repeating a job from quartz (Spring + Quartz application) - Job Chaining

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have the following setup for my quartz job -

```
    <bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="actualObject" /><br>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="processData"/>
    <property name="concurrent" value="false"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="10000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="1000" />
</bean>
```

And this works good for me.
What I would like to do is to call the processData agai,n as soon as it finishes.
I know the good old while(true) method is best suited, but I want to do this with quartz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you must explain why you "*want to do this with quartz*" because the "*good old while(true)*" is the right way to implement your use case (of course you need an extra thread, but Quartz needs that as well). It sounds like over-engineering so you'll better have a good reason.

That being said you have two choices:

- reschedule the job to run immediately when you leave it. In principle:

  ```
  public class HelloJob implements Job {

      public HelloJob() {
      }

      public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
      {
          //do your job...

          Trigger trigger = newTrigger().build();
          JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class).build();
          context.getScheduler().scheduleJob(trigger, job);
      }
  }
  ```

  You don't need your XML configuration but must schedule this job to run for the very first time somehow (e.g. in `@PostConstruct` using `Scheduler` directly). The momemnt your job finishes, it will run the same job again as it was just rescheduled.
- [`JobChainingJobListener`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html) might work for you, see: [Can Quartz Scheduler Run jobs serially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134903)

Both solutions are very heavyweight compared to "*good old while(true)*".

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz. I wanted this to be in quartz because of my current requirement of scheduling a job which changes the status of the system with each iteration. I should be writing it such as it is extendable at a later point in development. Any code based examples or links for the JobChainingListener would be great. I am no Quartz expert, but I would like to see some code.