# Java + Spring + Quartz-scheduler: Fire a job after the ending of other jobs

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have this problem:

I have several jobs scheduled. Every job produces a file. Now I have to schedule another job that picks all these files, compresses them and sends via FTP to a remote server.

So the last job has to wait until completion of the other jobs to start. How can I schedule this job? Can you give me some examples?

I'm using Spring integration with Quartz.

Comment: Related: [*Can Quartz Scheduler Run jobs serially?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134903)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @  [JobListner](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-07)

Add a logic, in

```
public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
            JobExecutionException jobException);
```

To check , are all jobs completed or not.

I hope this helps